# Understanding a proof of Hartshorne's book proposition 2.2.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

> I have been reading the book Algebraic Geometry by Robin Hartshorne
>   and I have found  the following proposition:

[image]

> For part b) the proof goes as follows:

[image]

> The thing is that, How can we ensure that $f \in \sqrt{a}$?. And I
>   really don't follow proof that $\psi $ surjective. That goes as
>   follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> So I hope someone can help me understanding this parts of this proof.
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, let me post the proof of the surjectivity :) can you help me with that?

Comment: Ready I have edited my post

Answer (score 1):

It's in the lemma 2.1. $V(\mathfrak{a}) \cap D(f) = \varnothing$ is equivalent to $V(\mathfrak{a}) \subset V(f)$, which according to lemma 2.1 means that $\sqrt{(f)} \subset \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$, so $f \in \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$.

Comment: Thank you, let me post the proof of the surjectivity :) can you help me with that?

Comment: Ready :) I have edited my post

Comment: The idea is to use a "partition of unity" argument. I recommend looking at Ravi Vakil's course notes, it's much more clearly explained over there.

Comment: Ok let me check just a second :) If I have questions, can I leave you a comment ?

Comment: In Hartshorne's proof,  why can we cover a basic open set $D_f$ with open sets $V_i$?

Comment: Which page I should consult from those notes? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf It's theorem 4.1.2. Vakil defines the structural sheaf a bit differently than Hartshorne, and theorem 4.1.2 basically proves the equivalence of these two definitions. To understand Vakil's approach, you need to read more of the background information in his notes (e.g. at some point he just says "(quasicompactness of Spec A, Exercise 3.5.C).", which Harthshorne's does explicitly on the top of page 72), but I consider his more "high-level" approach more insightful.

Comment: Right, So let me check it out again and if I have more questions, Can I let you know?